# Impossible to create an email address from the postfix admin

Tags: dns, email, postfix, webserver

Good morning,
I am doing a year-end project which consists in creating a postfix mail server, I arrived at the creation of emails except that when I want to create an impossble mail addendum I have the following message

`The s2itec.com domain is invalid and/or not resolvable via DNS`

do you have a solution?

I used this tutorial:

https://neptunet.fr/messagerie-debian/

I changed the php version because I use version 7.4.30 too old, I changed the mode of intallation and I put my ip address in local. I am using Debian version 11

I took the packet directly from the postfix github: https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin/blob/master/INSTALL.TXT

This is the 3.3.10 version of postfix admin

Thank you in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYgXS.png

Answer (score 2):

The issue is "*The s2itec.com domain is invalid and/or not resolvable via DNS*". Do you understand what this means?

In particular please note from your tutorial,

> Je pars du principe que vous avez déjà dans votre infrastructure un serveur DNS paramétré et fonctionnel pour votre domaine.
>
> I assume that you already have in your infrastructure a configured and functional DNS server for your domain. - *Google Translate*

You must use a domain that is correctly set up